# how to extract and combine the interface in the array into a union

Tags: typescript

The real example is that I want to implement a function that returns an object containing all the attributes in the input array by entering an object array.

```
function unit<T extends object>(arr: T[]) {
  let obj = {};
  arr.forEach((val) => {
    obj = { ...obj, ...val };
  });
  return obj;
}

const a = { name: "l" };
const b = { age: 1 };

const person = unit([a, b]);
```

[image]

I want person to be a dynamic typescript value based on input, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: does `type Arr = (A & B)[];` not work? how about `Array<A & B>`?

Comment: There may be C and B in the future. I hope I don't have to make a statement

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do

Comment: TypeScript can't follow this sort of higher order type manipulation by itself, but you can get the desired typings as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjXp6m). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining.  If not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz It looks a little complicated, but I think it's what I want.

Comment: thats really cool I never knew typescript lets you add parameters for types so you can delegate them

Comment: I will write up an answer, but I'm worried that you only "think" it's what you want.  Have you tried it with whatever use cases you care about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't model mutation of types in loops, so there's no way the compiler will be able to figure out the resulting type of `obj` will be for you.  You'll have to tell it what type you expect explicitly.

So, what do we expect?  Well, I propose that

```
const person = unit([a, b]);
```

should result in `person` being the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the types of `a` and `b`:

```
// const person: { name: string; } & { age: number; }
```

Note that this won't really be right if the various elements of `arr` have conflicting property types.  If you wrote `unit([{a: 0}, {a: ""}])`, the resulting value would not really be of type `{a: number} & {a: string}`.  Spreading overwrites properties; it does not intersect them.  Still, this is close enough and is often what the compiler does anyway when you spread generic things together:

```
function spread<T extends object, U extends object>(t: T, u: U) {
  const v = { ...t, ...u };
  // const v: T & U
}
```

So that's our goal: produce an intersection of the types of each element of `arr`.

---

First, you should make the `unit()` function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of `arr`, like this:

```
function unit<T extends object[]>(arr: [...T]) {
```

(where `[...T]` is a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) that gives the compiler the hint that we'd like `T` to be a tuple type if possible)

Otherwise, if you leave it as just generic in the *element types* of `arr`, then your type argument `T` will end up being a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of every element type, which is hard to tease apart into its constituents.  For example, examine the difference between `person` and `notPerson`:

```
const notPerson = unit([Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : b]);
// const notPerson: { name: string; } | { age: number; }
```

In both cases, in your version, `T` would be inferred as `{name: string} | {age: number}`.  But `person` should be of type `{name: string} & {age: number}` while `notPerson` should be of type `{name: string} | {age: number}`.  In order to keep those separate then, we need to care not just about the union of all element types, but each individual element type separately.

---

Okay, so, armed with `T` being a tuple, how do we convert it to an intersection of its element types?  Like this:

```
type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> =
  { [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void }[number] extends
  (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;
```

This uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) from a contravariant type position to turn a union into an intersection.  The technique is similar to the way [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218) works.

The we can just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `obj` is of the type `TupleToIntersection<T>`:

```
  let obj = {} as TupleToIntersection<T>;
```

but if we do that, the compiler will forget that `obj` is object-like and will get mad when you spread it.  So let's remind it by using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

```
  let obj = {} as Extract<TupleToIntersection<T>, object>;
```

That will be the same as `TupleToIntersection<T>` as long as it is truly objectlike and not primitive.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const person = unit([a, b]);
// const person: { name: string; } & { age: number; }
const notPerson = unit([Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : b]);
// const notPerson: { name: string; } | { age: number; }
const anotherThing = unit([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: true }, { e: "" }]);
// const anotherThing: { a: number; } & { b: number; } & { c: number; } & 
//  { d: boolean; } & { e: string; }
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABOGUA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdE4AjAK22gG0BdAPgAoBDAJw4C5E6A6QRgYBKRAG8AUIkQAbbFHLVEAXgkBfRGzIBRfBzbRMIAA7yMcAJJgCHErVgJMTADRKa0JgG5pWrv2A4Dh1DAAsWFgA3NlkxFSYJXxlKKlUJREF+FLdM6NlEdR8ZdREixA4FEA4kFJ91SUlQSEckEhMKtiJMHHxCUncHNwBVHoJiMhSHViheDDcQXiGxKRkIBBJFSLTxDMEoHMEQArKAehPENbANxEjZxAAyRCHJeslL67ZtxDA2AFtsXgAIlkgOOb3WigoXzYAHMAYgAIxg8FXRQmbB2BBpFBQFh0NhuCiiHxnC4QxDozFgXg7H7-XgbDgwMAwrwFB7pWHwsAgX4UDFs+rvRRgOBQAAKGJIWLUOLxAFk2FBQvwDMQ4L8WGI0IgAAz8ACsiAA-FpELwiaVJKThd8xZKqTTvn94Yzmaz2QAfTlw3g8vkCgooj6i5UYjChd3YsCoPE7Ni8JHqNw7Ci8ABMBRTF14AGYs+kiLwoBwQNgCzt4YDQepidbzra2KHQuHIyynQnvrz+RxBRzU37u4HNI8dhBBwHe+zR4gi4gKHA4PIm32Z66S+7BQ1JFAAJ7oxAYUzmKw2KUOeBgbp4Mb9Ju7xgJFS+HZ0SyIZmIADW2F3cGAh4MLwLC4LMb6iKoCSRHAMBEAUdD+j2DCjH0JC+CBvDMsAGKIJYcRQTBcGmu+frYJEAqSEAA)

Comment: Very professional.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
type A = { [key: string]: string | number }

type Arr = A[]

const test3: Arr = [{a: "a", b: 1}]

console.log(test3)
```